# Can't find canvas element created inside div

Tags: javascript, canvas, gojs

I'm trying to create a canvas element which does not show on UI and draw GoJS data to it

```
    const divElement: HTMLDivElement = document.createElement('div')
    divElement.id='pngCanvas';
    divElement.style.height='1000px';
    divElement.style.width='1000px';
    const floorNameData=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('floorNameArray'))
    const selectedFloor = floorNameData.find((item, index) => {
        return item.selected === true;
    });
    const mappedModelData=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('floorArray'))[selectedFloor.floorId]
    const fpInstance: Floorplan = new Floorplan(divElement);
    var virtualCanvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    debugger
    fpInstance.model = go.Model.fromJson(mappedModelData);
```

GoJS draws a canvas element to assigned div,
I see the canvas as innerHTML of div element.
How to retrieve the canvas element and style so I can convert to png without showing in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be depending on the existence of a Canvas element within the HTML DIV element.  It is not part of the supported API, so you cannot depend on that.

Instead you should call **Diagram.makeImage** or **Diagram.makeImageData**.  https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Diagram.html#makeImage

Read more about rendering at: https://gojs.net/latest/intro/makingImages.html.  Also consider: https://gojs.net/latest/intro/makingSVG.html.

Comment: But I don't have canvas at the moment, I want to make png from goJS json I have available. How to do that?

Comment: If you do not want the user to see the diagram on the page, create a hidden DIV and its **Diagram**. Initialize the **Diagram**, including the model, and then call **Diagram.makeImage**.

Answer (score 2):

He problem is that the `div` is not in the document, so `document.querySelector('canvas')` will return nothing since it looks in the document.

Change

```
var virtualCanvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
```

to

```
var virtualCanvas = divElement.querySelector('canvas');
```